# Is anyone utilizing Component-Based Development (UML Components by Cheesman and Daniels)?

Tags: architecture, components, uml

UML Components is a Component-Based Development method by Cheesman and Daniels (2001) which is described in the same named [book](http://www.syntropy.co.uk/umlcomponents/).

My university has a UML Component Development module teaching exclusively from the aforementioned book. I've learned quite well, but can't find anyone in the industry using it.

Is UML Components simply one particular method which has been selected for educational purposes as a good example of Component-Based Development? There are certainly more universities teaching it, i.e. [The University of Helsinky](http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/przybils/courses/CBD06/bibliography.html)

---

### UML Components

After conducting a research on my own initiative, I found that there was something called CBD CAB (~1999). The Component-Based Development Customer Advisory Board no longer exists. It had 80 worldwide member organizations and the aim was best practices in Component-Based Development.

Cheesman's prediction that the OMG group may adopt his method in the future didn't fulfill. The OMG adopted [SysML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systems_Modeling_Language) which originated in January, 2001. Cheesman worked on Component-Based Development in Sterling Software which was acquired by CA in 2000. He co-authored several [publications on CBD](http://www.stratasoftware.com/company_method.html) and now he is the [director](http://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=100364&authType=NAME_SEARCH&authToken=XeDz&locale=en_US&srchid=30e0c80d-67d6-43f4-b0af-60493d622f02-0&srchindex=1&srchtotal=3&goback=.fps_PBCK_*1_John_Cheesman_*1_*1_*1_*1_*2_*1_Y_*1_*1_*1_false_1_R_*1_*51_*1_*51_true_*1_gb:0_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2_*2&pvs=ps&trk=pp_profile_name_link) at [Strata Software](http://www.stratasoftware.com/).

### Other CBD Methods

Catalysis (Desmond D’Souza and Alan Cameron Wills 1999), KobrA (Atkinson 2001), Fusion (Coleman 1993), OPEN process framework (Graham, Henderson-Sellers & Younessi, 1997), Business Component Factory (Herzum and Sims 2000), RUP (Jacobson 1999), and more.

### Resources

Wikipedia mentions [Catalysis II](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalysis_software_design_method) built on top of Catalysis, UML Components, and other methods. There is also one relatively modern known as [rCOS](http://rcos.iist.unu.edu/) (2005), then a [publication](http://www.springer.com/computer/swe/book/978-3-540-35628-8) on Component-Based Software Engineering (2006), [wikipedia resources](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Computer_Programming/Component_based_software_development#Impacts_of_CBSD), and even a [CBSE International Conference](http://cbse-conferences.org/2012/) (2012) from the ACM Special Interest Group on Software Engineering.

### Current Situation

With the help of a book ([Component-Based Software Development: Case Studies](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=vmXxG-PZvWcC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Kung Kiu Lau), it started making sense.

There is a really large amount of various component frameworks on the market for all modern languages. Eventually, a new one can be developed and re-used.

### Possible Answer

Therefore, CBD / CBSE are successfully used in the industry; however, it's somewhat confusing to start studying the problematics from UML Components by Cheesman & Daniels. To conclude, modern component identification approaches and methodologies are described in Component-Based Software Engineering international symposiums, one of which is [the CBSE 12th International Symposium (2009)](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=8cdWHmE4U5oC&printsec=frontcover&dq=component-based%20software%20engineering&hl=en&sa=X&ei=0N4qT6njKI6p8QOkmbXvDg&ved=0CEoQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=component-based%20software%20engineering&f=false). Open it to find what is available today.

Note: *I intentionally didn't answer my question with the answer button, so that it's open for suggestions. If you have an experience with CBD, please post it as an answer*

Comment: This is the most valuable book on CBD I found: Component Software: Beyond Object-Oriented Programming by Clemens Szyperski with Dominik Gruntz and Stephan Murer. http://www.amazon.co.uk/Component-Software-Object-Oriented-Programming-Addison-Wesley/dp/032175302X Not only it can be a good introduction, the book also describes solutions from the 3 most major vendors of component frameworks today (OMG vs. Oracle vs. Microsoft)

Comment: http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=355016 - click the "Cited By" tab to see who else read the book and mentioned it in a research paper as a reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read the book and found it very useful in the industry despite the fact that in 13 years, I never found anyone following a book literally.

For my practical experience: seven years ago, I was in a startup and we needed to build  an [Unstructured Information Management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UIMA) server. We used the component approach to draw the system components from use cases and quality attributes, mixing the Kobra rules and principles of component composition, aggregation, and definition with the [Design by Contract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract) definition of UML CBD which is about deriving interfaces from use cases and activity / sequence diagrams.

Then we did some benchmarking and spike to see what we can find as open source components and what we need to build. We matched interfaces described by us at the component level with those present in open source components. For example, we needed a [Named-Entity Recognition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition) engine. We derived the interfaces from our use cases and activity diagrams, researched some Open Source components, and finally decided for [Annie from GATE](http://gate.ac.uk/sale/tao/splitch6.html#x9-1240006). We chose it also because GATE internally uses the component-based approach for various parts of the NLP engine.

In a few words, it was amazing because we could divide and conquer the system. Some parts were developed by us, other could be reused from open source component-based systems. If you use the component approach, there is no difference between "buy" and make in the technological model of the [Zachman Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zachman_Framework).

So the benefit of the approach for us was to have an objective view of what we have to do and what we can build. In a few weeks, we had a working prototype and could go back to our stakeholders.

> Ideally, you've never stopped using it, or found some other CBD method
>   which works better

I think I never started using it literally, but I never stopped using this principle. Simply because in the industry, you use books as a pianist uses books during a concert.
Books teach principles and knowledge, not practices and competencies. 
You can read awesome books about piano playing, but if you don't practice you'll never be a pianist; however, if you practice and don't read the book, you probably won't be as good as you could be.

In a few words: I think the class is worth it.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Your answer is now rewarded with 150 reputation points. Enjoy!

Answer (score 4):

I've never heard of it.

In practice, UML is only (1) a loose communication method, where no-one care about the the ins-and-outs of its "formal" aspects; or (2) a way for large consultancies to pretend to be doing useful work.

Similarly, the 90s were a time in which people spoke a lot about "Components" (note the capital), and basically none of that came to much. What did happen was widespread open-source projects, and a much greater diffusion of learning and discussion about architectures.

So, I strongly doubt that what you learn in that module will be of practical application, or impress anyone.

Update: I'd add that it's somewhat misleading to think of "component based design" as some kind of specialist activity. All modern development (except for some embedded applications) uses substantial numbers of libraries, and almost all "business" or application software will use elements that can truly be characterised as components.

Answer (score 0):

Universities tend to teach all kind of things that are a very bad idea in practice and often are ten years behind industrial practices (and industry tends to ignore universities and fails to pick up scientific results). Real reusability is done at library level, not component. Or by copying whole applications and then changing them. It seems the overhead in describing and reasoning about component properties is too high, so the granularity of reuse has to be higher.

The last CBSE conference doesn't seem to have any industrial experience papers.

Comment: "Real reusability is done at library level, not component" So, you've never used an RDBMS, message queue, job queue, data structure server, web server, or web proxy?

Comment: @Marcin, that is not a component in terms of CBD

Comment: Really? None of those encapsulate operations and / or data in a pluggable manner?

Comment: @Stephan According to Cheesman and Daniels, the primary aim of CBD is building for change. Component reusability is an outcome. See Microsoft COM at http://www.microsoft.com/com/default.mspx. Microsoft built a large part of windows using COM/COM+/DCOM. Another good example is a component-based programming language such as Delphi, C++ Builder, Java, and others. CBD also provides the base to implement SOA.

Comment: Don't agree with the 'copying whole applications and then changing them.' Personally I haven't seen that happen in practice.

Comment: SOA is another disaster, but that's a different subject. CBD doesn't provide what is needed to handle change. It's called DLL hell for a reason. The component-based part of Delphi is a failure. If you want to be able to change, use smalltalk or lisp.

Comment: @Marek I'm fine, it's just the emperor has no clothes.

Comment: @Marcin, no they don't encapsulate operations and / or data in a pluggable manner. There is a difference between integrating them and being able to reason meaningful about resulting system properties. Nothing independent and composable about them.

Comment: @dsummersl In the past 15 years I've personally seen that a lot, and I know that it happens a lot in other contexts. Best practice in reuse, even.